# Get relative file path in a class library project that is being referenced by a web project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net website that references a class library. In the class library I need to read a file into memory.

At the top level of my class library there is a folder called `EmailTemplateHtml` containing the file `MailTemplate.html` that I want to read in.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 49):

In Visual Studio, you can configure your library such that the file is copied into the build directory of any project that depends upon it. Then you can get the path to the build directory at runtime in order to read your file.

Step by step instructions, starting from a fresh solution:

1. Create your application project and your class library project.
2. Add a *reference* to the class library project from the application project via *Properties*->*Add*->*Reference* from the application's context menu in *Solution Explorer*:

   [image: Screenshot showing the *Reference* option]
   [image: Screenshot showing *Reference Explorer*]
3. Create the file in your class library project that you need to read, then set its *Copy to Output Directory* property to either *Copy always* or *Copy if newer* via the *Properties* pane in *Solution Explorer*:

   [image: Screenshot showing the *Copy to Output Directory* option]
4. From within *either* the class library project *or* your application (either will work with exactly the same code), reference your file relative to `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`. For example:

   ```
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.IO;

   namespace MyLibrary
   {
       public class MyClass
       {
           public static string ReadFoo()
           {
               var buildDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
               var filePath = buildDir + @"\foo.txt";
               return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   (Note that back before .NET Core, you could use a file path relative to `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` instead, but this doesn't work in a .NET Core application because [the initial working directory for .NET Core apps is the source directory instead of the build directory](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2239), apparently because this was needed by ASP.NET Core.)
5. Go ahead and call your library code from your application code, and everything will work fine. e.g.:

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using MyLibrary;

   namespace AspCoreAppWithLib.Controllers
   {
       public class HelloWorldController : Controller
       {
           [HttpGet("/read-file")]
           public string ReadFileFromLibrary()
           {
               return MyClass.ReadFoo();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: While I am trying to add reference to text file on disk I am getting the error "make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or com component"

Comment: @user2934433 You can't add a reference to the text file itself - in step 2, I show adding a reference to the class library *project* that contains the text file.

Comment: got it! Another doubt here you are referring to the MyLibrary project, is there a way to do just by referring to dll?

Answer (score 7):

```
using System.IO;    
using System.Reflection;

public static string ExecutionDirectoryPathName()
    {
         var dirPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
         dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dirPath);
         return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(dirPath, "\EmailTemplateHtml\MailTemplate.html"));
    }
```

Comment: May need to escape slashes in returned string. Add '@' before string as such: return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(dirPath, @"\EmailTemplateHtml\MailTemplate.html"));

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find the path where the assembly is located; from within the assembly then use the following code:

```
 public static string ExecutionDirectoryPathName
 {
   get
     {
         var dirPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
         dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dirPath);
         return dirPath + @"\";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by a folder in the class library but you can use the current working directory if you wish to build a path as follows:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

You can then use the `Path.Combine()` method to build file paths.

Comment: Note that before .NET Core, this would return the same as `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` (given in other answers here), while in .NET Core it returns the path of the *source* directory instead of the build directory (which is broken for the OP's use case of having a distinct application project and class library project, since when the application is running its working directory *won't* contain files that are from the class library project).

Answer (score -4):

You can add a Static class in your class library with some static methods/properties to set. Set the values from Global.ascx.cs on start app method. Now you can get the values of class library.

Hope this makes clear.
Happy coding

Comment: This is too vague for me to understand the approach you're trying to describe. Some fundamental things - like what the "static methods/properties" you mention are meant to do or contain - are left unstated.