# get file path onto class library project c#

Tags: c#, filepath

I have a problem when I'll get file path onto class library project.
I have a `log4net.config` file into my class library project and I need get and read `log4net.config`. I test many solution:

1

```
var buildDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); 
var filePath = buildDir + @"\log4net.config";
```

2

```
var dirPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dirPath);
return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(dirPath, "\log4net.config"));
```

but I don't get any result. please suggest a solution.

Comment: Please, have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/837501/3270427

Comment: any result of your attemp?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer i find answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419694/get-relative-file-path-in-a-class-library-project-that-is-being-referenced-by-a